# What's the meaning of "you’re genuinely not coming through here"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> You’re genuinely not coming through here. There are always ethical
> choices around any work...

I know the meaning of [come through](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/come-through), but I don't understand the sentence in relationship with the text below.

Could you please explain it to me?

The text is here:

> ‘What you’re emphasizing here, Paul,’ Mr Capaldi was saying, ‘is how
> any work we do brands us. That’s your point, am I right? It brands us,
> and sometimes brands us unjustly.’ ‘That’s a very smart way of
> misunderstanding my point, Capaldi.’ ‘Paul, come on,’ the Mother said.
> ‘I’m sorry, Capaldi, if this sounds impolite. But frankly? I think
> you’re deliberately misconstruing what I’m saying.’ ‘No, Paul, **you’re
> genuinely not coming through here.** There are always ethical choices
> around any work. That’s true, whether we get paid for it or we don’t.’
> ‘That’s very considerate of you, Capaldi.’ ‘Paul, come on,’ the Mother
> said again. ‘Henry’s just doing what we asked him. No more, no less.’
> ‘It’s no wonder, Capaldi – Henry, sorry – a guy like you would
> struggle to understand what I’m saying here.’

*The Klara and The Sun* by Kazuo Ishiguro

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this context coming through means being understood.

The root of this expression would be from radio or telephone conversations where the sender could not be heard. You're not coming through clearly if your voice is distorted or otherwise un-understandable.

In a face to face conversation it would mean the listener does not understand the point you're making.